# Newton's Law of Cooling, age of Earth, weak math skills

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I'm curious about a problem concerning the age of the earth, but I don't have the math skills to think properly about it. I've found the solution to Newton's Law of Cooling, and I can handle that much:

$$T(t) = T_s + (T_0 - T_s)e^{-kt}$$

The part I'm stuck on is that I don't want to know the temperature of the whole earth. I want to know the temperature at the bottom of a deep mineshaft, and under two different conditions: (1) with Lord Kelvin's mistaken assumption that the interior of the earth is static and (2) with our current knowledge that the mantle convects.

I'm thinking that the way to approach condition (1) is to treat Earth as though it were made up of infinitely many concentric spheres, all infinitely thin, and then just graph the temperature at the bottom of the mineshaft. I'm too weak in calculus to figure out how to deal with the infinitely many spheres.

I'm thinking that the way to approach condition (2) is to treat the entire mantle as a single sphere that has a definite thickness and even temperature, among all the other infinitely thin spheres both inside it and out.

So I think I have the qualitative approach right, but I just don't have the math skills to consummate the deal. Can anyone show me the functions needed to graph the two cases over time?

Comment: In either case, this is not in any way an easy question to answer. It would involve a lot of calculus and computation I believe to get even a "good" estimate in both cases. For the convection part you'll have to look into convective heat transfer and equations relating all the various physical conditions that arise during such. When all is said and done, you must then expand what you have from 1D to 3 dimensions of space and the additional dimension of time, all of which will determine what the state of any given point within the Earth will be at any point in time.

Comment: Try this study from 2008: http://www.irsm.cas.cz/materialy/acta_content/2008_04/1_Torres.pdf

Comment: Given that you have asked questions about this before, I would advise that you nail down your calculus skills, all the way up to partial differential equations and multivariable-stuff, and then try to model the scenarios you're thinking of for yourself and then post them here or elsewhere for others to critique. The Physics exchange would probably be a better place to post these questions as well considering that, while there are a lot of applied mathematicians, Physicists might have their own neat way of attacking the problem.

Comment: Additionally, I'm guessing that a Lot of work has been done on the subject, and in my travels of the library here on campus I'm certain I've seen a number of good books on topics such as convective heat transfer, all of mathematics, obviously, and especially planetary science, which might also be a good place to read considering planetary scientists have been buzzing for the past ~two decades since research concerning Exoplanets really began. Sara Seager's books are great reads. A lot of the equations derived can be applied to Earth as well as to other planets.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather difficult problem to solve, but one can think about it qualitatively, at least. As it turns out, it is just as hard to find the temperature distribution at one point of the earth as it is everywhere.

Assume the earth is spherical and all the fields spherically symmetric: you'll still have two independent variables: distance from the center of the earth r and time t. The dependent variables are the temperature $T(r,t)$ and the phase of a slice at $r$ (liquid / solid)

The physical processes that can occur are

(1) heat conduction along r

(2) convection, which is a toughie to simplify to 1D without introducing sources / sinks

(3) Phase change from liquid to solid as the earth cools, absorbing the heat of phase 
transformation

(4) A nonlinear radiative boundary condition at the end r=Re (this is too important to 
ignore especially in the early stages of the earth)

(5) A source term if heat generation from radiation is included

(6) Shrinkage / expansion due to cooling

The initial conditions are the phase and initial temperature distribution of the earth at t=0.

You'll need to make a bunch of assumptions and need data for the (average) thermal conductivity $K$, or $K(T)$, specific heat capacity $c_p(T)$, latent heat of melting, the radiative constant $\sigma$, coefficient of thermal expansion $\alpha$ and some equivalent heat transfer law for the convective term and the densities $\rho(T)$.

You can formulate the above as a regular IBVP (initial-boundary value problem). Your solution will be T(r=r_{mantle}, t=4.5x10^9 years) :)

Of course, you could simplify things further. Ignore convection, for one thing. Or you could try to assume that the earth has been around for long enough that a steady-state approximation is good enough.

In any case, using Newton's law will not give you a very meaningful answer, I'm afraid.

Edited to add: The solid / liquid interface position $r_i$ will also arise as a result of the calculation. Of course, you will need different sets of properties for the different phases.